# How can I set session cookies to be Http-Only in servlet API 2.5?

Tags: java, servlets

How can I set session cookies to be Http-Only in servlet API 2.5?  The Cookie.setHttpOnly method was added in servlet API 3.0.

Comment: It really depends on the AppServer. See my previous answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps/1088009#1088009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps/1088009#1088009)

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean the JSESSIONID cookie specifically or cookies in general that don't live beyond the browser session.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but I came up with a solution - see my answer for [How do you configure HttpOnly cookies in tomcat / java webapps?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14610452/9822)

Answer (score 1):

i need to do the same thing...

i'm thinking of doing a servlet filter, reading the cookies with `request.getCookies()`, creating the raw cookies (in a StringBuilder; not the object Cookie), appending `HttpOnly` and using `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", rawCookies)` to put them back.

one thing to be carefull about is taking other properties, as in `domain`, `path`, `secured`; not just `name` and `value`

will let you know how it goes...

*PS: also thought of taking the header with `request.getHeader('COOKIES')` and using regex to append `HttpOnly`, but it seems that the header `COOKIES` will only give you the `name` and the `value` property*

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to create some utility code that will take a `Cookie` and a flag for whether or not you want `HttpOnly`. The utility will create the associated string header for the cookie which you can pass to `HttpServletResponse.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieHeader)`.