# jsp/servlet session id won't change after chrome close

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, session, servlets

As Title,
I close **chrome** and open it again but session id won't change.
But **Firefox** and **IE** work !!!!
Why?

```
    session = request.getSession();
    sessonId = session.getId();

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><head><title>TestSession</title></head><body>");
    out.print("sessionId: "+sessonId);
    out.print("</body></html>");
    out.close();
```

Comment: How do you understand about user session?

Comment: Check if you have them all clearing cookies on browser close or not.

Comment: To Loc : session would be destroyed when browser close ?
To developerwjk: After i clean , it works.
                 But it against meaning of the session ?
                 cos in IE or Firefox,i dont need to do it,users either

Comment: Browser handles the cookie. The cookie name in this case is JSESSIONID. When does a JSESSIONID is deleted ?

JSESSIONID doesn't have an expiration date : it's a session cookie. As all session cookies, it will be deleted when the broswer is closed. If you use the basic JSESSIONID mechanism, then the session will become unreachable after you close and re-open the browser, because JSESSIONID cookie is deleted.   Note that *All the tabs and windows* have to be closed to consider a browser as closed.  Refer -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099752/session-or-cookie-confusion