# How much my session will last

Tags: jsp, session

In a servlet page I set a session.

How much time will live?

```
 if( session.getAttribute!=null){

  while( rs.next())
     name=rs.getString("name");
     addres=rs.getString("address");
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically the session is alive as long as the user doesn't close her/his browser, or the session timeout is reached (default: 30min). You can define the maximum timeout using

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

in your deployment descriptor or in code using `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);`
The purpose of a session is to keep information on server-side between each request. Maybe you want to also read about session tracking..have a look here:
[Session or cookie confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099752/session-or-cookie-confusion)