# How can I create HttpOnly cookies using Servlet API 2.5?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, servlet-2.5

I'm working with a web application that uses Servlet API v2.5, running on Tomcat 6, and I need to send HttpOnly cookies to the client. I'm **not** talking about session cookies generated by the servlet container (which is covered excellently by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps)), but custom cookies added to the response using `response.addCookie()`.

The `Cookie#setHttpOnly()` method does not exist in v2.5, so I have to build the HTTP header myself and add the `HttpOnly` token. Is there an easy way to do this without rolling my own implementation of [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1) from scratch?

Comment: I'm confused. [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps/33461#33461) of the answers of the question you linked to describes `response.setHeader( "Set-Cookie", "name=value; HttpOnly");` for the simple use case where you do not need the server's session cookies. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: @Arjan I'm looking for a solution that handles character encoding, expiration dates, and all the other stuff defined in the RFC. Is there anything elsewhere in the Servlet API that can help me? (I'm willing to accept "there isn't" as an answer, if it's true.)

Comment: Ah, my bad, there's a lot more than just `name=value` of course. Did you check what `Cookie#toString()` gives you?

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, Cookie#getValue() just returns the (String) value part of the cookie's name-value pair.

Comment: (Sorry, edited my comment to make that `#toString()` -- but I guess you're out of luck there too.)

Comment: Oh, actually, though the Servlet 2.5's `Cookie#toString` just claims it's inherited from `Object`, [some other Java Cookie APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html#toString()) explicitly state: *"Convert the cookie to a string suitable for use as the value of the corresponding HTTP header."* So it might be worth a test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need to implement a `org.apache.catalina.Valve` (which works on a very similar philosophy to a Servlet Filter) and cast the cookies to `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie` so that you can access low-level details in order to stick 'HttpOnly' in there.

[Tomcat API JavaDocs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/)