# HttpOnly cookies on Tomcat 5.5.36

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, tomcat5.5, httponly

I saw on the thread [How do you configure HttpOnly cookies in tomcat / java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps) that Tomcat 5.5.(>28) is supposed to support vendor specific `useHttpOnly` attribute specified in `<Context>` elements.

I added this attribute to ALL contexts configured in my server.xml.

However, only the `JSESSIONID` was appended with `"; httpOnly"` flag. All other cookies are exactly like there were before I added `useHttpOnly="true"`.

```
Set-Cookie=
JSESSIONID=25E8F...; Path=/custompath; HttpOnly
mycustomcookie1=xxxxxxx; Path=/
mycustomcookie2=1351101062602; Path=/
mycustomcookie3=0; Path=/
mycustomcookie4=1; Path=/; Secure
mycustomcookie5=4000; Expires=Sat, 22-Oct-2022 17:51:02 GMT; Path=/
```

Is there anything else I need to change?

(upgrading to tomcat 6 or 7 is not an option for now. Our system uses a third party framework based on tomcat 5.5)

Answer (score 1):

The `useHttpOnly` configuration in the server indeed applies to server-controlled cookies such as `JSESSIONID` only.

For webapp-controlled cookies you've to manually create the entire cookie header yourself. The `Cookie` class is unsuitable as the [`setHttpOnly()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setHttpOnly%28boolean%29) method was introduced in Servlet 3.0, but you're using Tomcat 5.5 does as being a Servlet 2.4 container not have this method in `Cookie` class. You'd need to upgrade to at least Tomcat 7 which is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container.

You can manually create the in the question mentioned cookies as follows:

```
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "mycustomcookie1=xxxxxxx; Path=/; HttpOnly");
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "mycustomcookie2=1351101062602; Path=/; HttpOnly");
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "mycustomcookie3=0; Path=/; HttpOnly");
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "mycustomcookie4=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly");
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "mycustomcookie5=4000; Expires=Sat, 22-Oct-2022 17:51:02 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly");
```

It's indeed just a matter of adding the `HttpOnly` attribute to the cookie header value, separated by `;`.

If you'd like to transparently apply this on *all* cookies, then you might want to provide a custom [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) wherein the `addHeader()` and `setHeader()` methods are accordingly been overridden to check if a `Set-Cookie` header is been set and if so, then add `;HttpOnly` to the value when absent. This way you can keep using `addCookie()`.

Comment: So sad about this... I wish there was some kind of configuration to apply this globally to the server. I don't want to go all over my code changing calls from `response.addCookie(cookie)` to `response.addHeader(...)` and manually creating the cookies. Even if I had a servlet 3.0 container, it would be painful to go calling `setHttpOnly()` to every cookie created. :( I'll try the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` idea.

Comment: Are you dealing with so many cookies? Your code might need some refactoring then as well :)

Comment: They are not that many. About 12 of them. The problem is that the code is using Cookie class facilities such as secure, expiration path etc. If I change the code to use addHeader, I'll need to handle everything by myself. In addition, the code is not mine, I'm dealing with something, at least, 4 years old.