# How to turn off HTTP session timeout in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

Is it possible to turn off HTTP session timeout in Spring Security?

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785073/spring-why-session-get-expired-before-session-timeout) I see that the HTTP session timeout can be modified in web.xml like this:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But I did not find from the Spring Security manuals how to disable the timeout.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring) I see that the Spring Security uses a javax.servlet.http.HttpSession internally, which according to this [manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) can be set to never expire by calling method setMaxInactiveInterval(0).

Therefore it should be possible to change the session timeout by obtaining the HttpSession (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring) in an answer) and changing the maxInactiveInterval to 0. My question is, if I will do this the first time after the user has logged in, will the change persist in the HttpSession (i.e., in a next request, will the change in HttpSession will be still there?)

And is it possible to disable the session timeout in web.xml like this or not?

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And another question, what is the default HTTP session timeout in Spring Security?

Comment: You really don't want to do this. They could last for years, and tie up resources all that time. Set a large timeout that won't inconvenience your users. I use eight hours, but I suspect I'm going to have to cut it to four on resource consumption grounds.

Comment: Thank You for the comment, I did not think about this. Eight hours should be sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.The snippet below will keep the HTTPSession alive unless the session is invalidated explicitly

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```