# Getting error when I am trying to set the httpOnly flag

Tags: java, html

I am trying to set the flag HttpOnly with "cookie.setHttpOnly(true);" but I am getting this error "The method setHttpOnly(boolean) is not defined for the type Cookie" Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: seems similar issue to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147113/setting-an-httponly-cookie-with-javax-servlet-2-5

Comment: In which server are you running your app?