# How to add isHttpOnly and secure as true in cookie?

Tags: java

This piece of code I wrote to fulfill the purpose but its is not working it seems. Can you please help , something is wrong or missed here ?

```
   HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    final Cookie cookie = new Cookie("CPSESSIONID", session.getId());
    //cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setPath(";Path=/;HttpOnly;");
    cookie.setSecure(true);
    res.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Please share your opinion for above concerns raised ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookie.setHttpOnly(true);` to consider as HtttpOnly. It controls if this cookie will be hidden from scripts on the client-side.

Comment: we don't have setHttpOnly() method in servlet 2.5 version so tried above way by setting path  even secure also it is not working.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147113/setting-an-httponly-cookie-with-javax-servlet-2-5

Comment: You mean below snippet is also not working?
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "CPSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");