# HttpOnly flag can't work on tomcat6.0.36

Tags: httponly

I have tried many ways to use the `httponly` flag to prevent `XSS` attack, but all failed.

Common way is to set use HttpOnly=`true` in context.xml

For test the result:  in the java code set two test parameters in the cookie and in front jsp file include javascript to alert the`document.cookie`, the two test parameters set in java code are get and show in the alert.

Java code:

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie("httponlytest","testsss");  
 response.addCookie(cookie); 
 Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("testhttponly","successfu"); 
 response.addCookie(cookie1);
```

javascript in jsp file:

```
alert("cookie------------"+document.cookie);
```

1. Is there anything i did wrong?
2. If you know how, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For others who do not know HttpOnly:

**HttpOnly=true** is a relative new attribute to make a cookie in the browser inaccessible to JavaScript.

So it is a browser-only security (XSS) technique to prevent accessing JSESSION_ID (hijacking java sessions) and such.

So you could always set the HttpOnly attribute in the Cookie itself. For the Java session ID it is now default I think, at least it should be.

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
```

This seems to work only for JSESSIONID. I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps) in SO.

Comment: You mean by setting useHttpOnly="true" in context is just work for JSESSIONID, the cookie set in backend java code can still be get by javascript,right? if so,does it can prevent from XSS attack? You said right, if setSecure(true) for cookie in java code, this cookie can't be get by javascript.

Comment: `setSecure` is for `https:`. Use [Cookie.setHttpOnly(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was dealing with **http-only=true** cookies. During my research i found that Mozilla and Chrome do not allow java applets to use **http-only=true** cookies. I was getting issue in accessing the JsessionidSSO cookie. During my research on bugs of JAVA i found [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7196513)
While in IE there is no issue in reading the cookies as IE has provided [InternetGetCookieEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API's to access **http-only** cookies and added the flag [INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/06/04/understanding-the-new-wininet-flag-internet-cookie-httponly.aspx) available only IE8 and above versions. So the problem of accessing the http-only cookies still not solved as java proposed the fix in java 7 update 40 while the current version is java 7 update21.