# Why is request.getsession() not returning the same session

Tags: java, session, cookies, cookie-httponly

I am developing a single page web application. I have included a java filter to intercept the html page request. So in this filter I am creating a session using `request.getSession()`.
And then I am setting the `JSESSIONID` cookie explicitly as I have to set the `HttpOnly` flag in the response header `Set-Cookie` to prevent the XSS attack through `document.cookie` on client side.

Now after login I need the session, so I am accessing the session using `request.getSession()`. And according to the `HttpServletRequest` javadoc [HttpServletRequest javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)

> request.getSession() returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

But I am getting a different session after login.

Comment: Define "different" session? A different instance than you expect or...?

Comment: @user1109519 A different session id is getting created and hence a different `JSESSIONID` cookie is sent to the browser than the previous one.

Comment: Are you setting the `JSESSIONID` every time in the filter? Show some code of the filter.

Comment: Have you tried making that change at the container level (e.g. Tomcat) instead of changing the headers yourself? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps.

Answer (score 1):

I will retrun same session if your requesting the application with same browser, if in case if your requesting from another browser it will return new session.