# httpOnly not working with spring inetrnationalization

Tags: spring, internationalization

httpOnly flag is not working in spring internationalization. I have set the HttpOnly flag in the response header Set-Cookie as follows

```
String sessionid = httpReq.getSession().getId();
httpRes.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + ";HttpOnly");
```

It working fine every where except internationalization part.Am suing spring 3 version and the servlet container is tomcat . How to set this

Can any one please help to solve this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't set the session id cookie like that, use the web.xml configuration for that. For the internationalization, assuming you are using the `CookieLocaleResolver` set the `cookieHttpOnly` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all setting the `httpOnly` option that way is a really bad way imho (you are for instance loosing the path/domain of the cookie). You should use configuration for that. How the session cookie is going to be written can be configured in the web.xml.

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

If you are an a servlet container that doesn't support the Servlet 3.0 spec in most cases there are configuration options to enable it.

For I18N you need to configure a `CookieLocaleResolver` and set the `cookieHttpOnly` property to `true`.

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @Deinum thanks For you help..I had done like this                <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
   <property name="cookieName" value="clientlanguage"/>
   <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="31449600"/>
</bean>                                                                as per your guidance i have added                                <property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="true"/>       but i am getting error like this "Invalid property 'cookieHttpOnly' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver]"

Comment: First of all We are using servlet 2.5 ,It does not support <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config> .So we have upgraded our servlet version and tried the same , but the JessionId created not suffixed with httpOnly tag.

Comment: Make sure your web.xml also has the proper version (3.0) else it won't work. If the property isn't there on the `CookieLocaleResolver` you are using an old version of Spring you should do an upgrade to a version that has support for this version (something in the 3.x range).

Comment: Please add the information to your question as that is crucial information, also please specify WHICH servlet container (tomcat, jetty or.... ) you are using.

Comment: @Deinum thanks for your kind help.We were using tomcat 6 and spring 3.1.1.It starts working when we upgraded both tomcat to 7 and spring to 3.2.12,But on our server tomcat 6 is using and we cannot change it.Could please tell me why cookieHttpOnly is not working with tomcat 6.We have replaced the spring servlet with tomcat 7's 
it doesn't work and i wont prefer this as I know its not a good way.So please help me to find a solution to implement cookieHttpOnly in tomcat 6

Comment: `cookieHttpOnly` works only for Servlet 3.0 enabled containers, Tomcat 6 isn't. How to enable it, by default, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps.