# How to fix "Cookie set without httpOnly" security Issue in GWT

Tags: java, security, cookies, tomcat7, smartgwt

We have developed a web application using Java and GWT, Now we are fixing the following issues:

Security Issues:

1. X-Frame-Options:
2. X-XSS-Protection:

Cookie:

3. HttpOnly and Secure

From the above 3 issues we are able to fix the first 2 issues but unable to fix third issue, because we are accessing cookies created by server at client side which is developed with GWT(javascript). So We are thinking that, it can not be fixed for our application Or can it be ignored because we fixed for "X-Frame-Options" which disallows javascript injection into our website.

Please give me suggestion about our above issue.

Comment: What is you application server?

Comment: We are using apache tomcat-7(.0.63)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/how-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-tomcat-java-webapps and https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, Thank for the link, Since we are using gwt at client side, we can not do all the stuff at tomcat level.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu: Please share how you resolved all those security issues. I am facing exactly same problem with one of my application developed using smartgwt deployed in JBoss 5.

Answer (score 1):

> HttpOnly and Secure

You can set the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) on cookies and you will still be able to access them via JavaScript. Please note that the whole of the application that uses GWT will need to be accessed over https for this to work.

If your application requires that all cookies are read via JavaScript then you cannot set the [http only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag. Please note that this is only important for session or authentication cookies - if it is possible to set those to http only and leave your others without the flag then this is the way to go.

Note that X-Frame-Options does not provide any more protection against JavaScript injection into your website than normal. The [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) does this as standard. X-Frame-Options simply prevents your site loading into a frameset or IFrame to mitigate [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Answer (score 0):

The GWT `Cookies.setCookie` method doesn't support `HttpOnly`.  You can just create your own `setCookie` method to set it if you like.  However, you won't be able to read the cookie from JavaScript if you do.

I needed to set the cookie value `SameSite` to be `Lax`, so just created the following method:

```
public static native void setCookie(String name, String value, double expires, boolean secure) /*-{
    var c = name + '=' + value;
    if (expires)
        c += ';expires=' + (new Date(expires)).toGMTString();
    if (secure)
        c += ';secure;SameSite=Lax';
    $doc.cookie = c;
}-*/;
```

Easy!  :)